# How to make colored boxes with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Helo,
I want to create small colored boxes indicating for each one the meaning of the colors. I found that code and don't know how to resize

```
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">.bg-primary</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">.bg-secondary</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-success text-white">.bg-success</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">.bg-info</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">.bg-light</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">.bg-dark</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-white text-dark">.bg-white</div>
```

I want the text to be side by side with the box
Thanks in advance

Comment: I was not sure about how you wanted the output to be. So, I have posted two answers below. Please check and see if any of them helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap grid system to resize each of the box's sizes. You can refer the code below -

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">.bg-primary</div>
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">.bg-secondary</div>
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-success text-white">.bg-success</div>
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">.bg-info</div>
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">.bg-light</div>
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">.bg-dark</div>
<div class="col-2 p-3 mb-2 bg-white text-dark">.bg-white</div>
</div>
```

And for having blocks as squares, use the following -

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.row>*{
  display:flex;
  height:200px ;
  width:200px ;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

*{
  background-color: CornSilk;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div class="row m-2">
<div class="bg-primary text-white">.bg-primary</div>
<div class="bg-secondary text-white">.bg-secondary</div>
<div class="bg-success text-white">.bg-success</div>
<div class="bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
<div class="bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>
<div class="bg-info text-white">.bg-info</div>
<div class="bg-light text-dark">.bg-light</div>
<div class="bg-dark text-white">.bg-dark</div>
<div class="bg-white text-dark">.bg-white</div>
</div>
```

If you were looking for something different, do let me know. Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank yu so much for your answer, I want squares (same height and weight) it's for explaining color codes I used If you have an Idea that would be grate

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is wrong. You can have the color placed side by side to the text with the same div.

It should look something like this:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>


<div class="row"> <!-- Sometimes bootstrap override display -->
      <div class="col text-black">
       .bg-primary
      </div>
      <div class="col bg-primary">
       <div style="padding: 50px;"></div> <!-- For demonstration -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two different divs/spans inside a div if you want to get a box with text beside it. So, you could do it using the bootstrap grid system as follows -

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-primary</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2  bg-secondary text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-secondary</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2  bg-success text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-success</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2  bg-danger text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-danger</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2  bg-warning text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-warning</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2  bg-info text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-info</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2  bg-light text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-light</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2  bg-dark text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-dark</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="col-6 p-3 mb-2  bg-white text-white"></div><span class="p-3 mb-2"> => .bg-white</span>
</div>
```

If you want the blocks to be square, you can use the following code -

```css
.row>* {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="bg-primary text-white"></div><span> => .bg-primary</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2  bg-secondary text-white"></div><span> => .bg-secondary</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2  bg-success text-white"></div><span> => .bg-success</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2  bg-danger text-white"></div><span> => .bg-danger</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2  bg-warning text-white"></div><span> => .bg-warning</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2  bg-info text-white"></div><span> => .bg-info</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2  bg-light text-white"></div><span> => .bg-light</span>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2  bg-dark text-white"></div>
  <spa> => .bg-dark</spa>
</div>
<div class="row m-2">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2  bg-white text-white"></div><span> => .bg-white</span>
</div>
```

You can read more about the bootstrap grid system [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp).

Comment: Can you tell me if I can't have square (same heigth and weight)  with col please?

Comment: @maya You can have the block as square too. You would have to use css to get the block in form of square.

Comment: @maya Checkout my edit. I have added code to make the blocks as square